# Is netstat -an same as netstat -na?

Tags: linux, networking, netstat

I am working on linux, and came across instances netstat -an and netstat -na.

Are they both same.what are their significance

Comment: We live in 21st century and we are supposed to migrate to `ss -a` (`ss` doesn't resolve names by default, no need for `-n`.)

Answer (score 3):

Both having the same effect.

Most of the programs found on a GNU/Linux system, as `netstat`, using the glibc function `getopt` for parsing their command line arguments. That's why you have to look at the documentation of GNU `getopt`, especially it's argument syntax which follows the POSIX standard. Here it is: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html

However, not all programs are using this syntax. Especially shell scripts or programs written in a language that has no bindings for GNU `getopt`. This means the question can't be answered in general, you need to check the man page if you want to know the exact argument syntax for a certain program. But `netstat` uses `getopt`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter how you pass the arguments to below,

```
while ((i = getopt_long(argc, argv, "MCFA:acdegphinNorstuVv?wxl", longopts, &lop)) != EOF)
   switch (i) {
     ...
   case 'a':
      flag_all++;
      break;
   case 'n':
      flag_not |= FLAG_NUM;
      break;
     ...
```

Just the cases `a` & `n` are enabled which is processed later with the respective flags set.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in "-an" and "-na"